# JavaScript clock: time interval conflicts

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clock

Hi I'm new to programming and am working on a JavaScript clock. I got it to change background color depending on whether it's an even or odd minute, and it changes text color every hour. However, I'm having trouble integrating a third task in: I'm trying to get it to change to a random color every five minutes, thus overriding the even-or-odd statements. So minute 1: odd, minute 2: even, 3: odd, 4: even, 5: RANDOM COLOR.

Since the function to change the background color every five minutes ([lines 75 to 83](https://github.com/Tamenze/clocky/blob/master/main.js#L75-L83)) is set on an interval, that conflicts with the interval set for getting the date ([line 71](https://github.com/Tamenze/clocky/blob/master/main.js#L71)).

As it stands now, the effects of Tasks 2 and 3 are not visible until Task 1 is commented out. Is there a way to perhaps combine Task 1 with the if/else statement on lines 11-24, so that all my tasks can run concurrently?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: The relevant portion of your code must be posted into your actual question, not available only via an external link.  That is a rule here at StackOverflow because external links tend to disappear or change over time rendering the question useless over time.

Comment: You should not use *setInterval* as it is not required to run at exactly the time you specify, so will run a little later each time (maybe nanoseconds, maybe milliseconds, maybe more). Use *setTimeout* and calculate the time for the next call each time. Also, do not set several intervals or timeouts, use one timeout to run all logic in the required sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single timer function to carry out all events. To get more accurate timing, set your timer to execute once every 100 milliseconds and maintain a counter. Based on the counter value, you can execute specific tasks at various intervals and also check for overlap of intervals. The counter can be reset when it reaches the largest interval you need to track.

Here is a sample:

```
var counter = 0;
var oldsec = 0;
setInterval(function(){timerInt()}, 100);

function timerInt(){
    // Read system clock and get seconds
    if (seconds <> oldsec) {
        // Update clock time here and set oldsec=seconds
    }


    // Execute other tasks
    if (counter % 3000 == 0) {  // Executes once every 5 minutes (300*10)

    }
    else if (counter % 1200 == 0) {  // Executes once in 2 minutes (120*10)

    }
    else if (counter % 600 == 0) {  // Executes once a minute (60*10)

    }

    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 3000) counter = 0;
}
```

You can use `if` and `else` to control which tasks to execute. Your clock seconds update will also be more accurate and will not "skip" seconds like it would with a 1000 millisecond timer.

Comment: This will not work properly in the case of clock drift or setTimeout callbacks which are delayed for whatever reason.

Comment: There cannot be any clock drift as we would read from the system clock and then update the text. If callbacks are delayed due to some reason, then all timer-based solutions would be affected. Anyway, this is a simple clock project and I imagine would not have heavy-duty code running alongside. :)

Comment: You are precisely **not** reading from the system clock. You are assuming that the callback will occur every tenth of a second precisely, but actually it never will. I don't think a clock that doesn't tell time accurately is a very good clock. There are perfectly good ways to deal with this. They are all based on querying the real system clock on each callback.

Comment: The callback does not need to happen exactly at a tenth of a second. And yes, I WILL read from the system clock and update the time. The code I posted is an incomplete example that just shows the outline of the timer loop. Sorry if that is not clear.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean - It would be better to check the time every 100 milliseconds and update the time if the second had changed from the previous (which would need to be stored). Have updated the code.